# How can I get contour subplots with different max values to all map to the same colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, subplot

I'm attempting to create three contour subplots (Python) next to each other, with one colorbar at the end that maps each contour to the same colors.  The contours have max values of 0.35, 0.28, and 0.24 respectively, and when I try to plot a colorbar to the right of the third figure, it only maps to one of the contours.  How can I fix this?

My code is as follows:

```
clf()

q = np.arange(0.5,1.0,0.005)
m2 = 1.448*(q+1.)**0.2/(q**0.6)
m1 = m2*q
X=0.3

r = np.arange(10,14,0.04)

Mass_array = np.zeros((len(r),len(m2))) # 80x80 array with first axis being R values, second axis is M2 values

Stdev = np.zeros((100,100))
DCPDisk = np.zeros((100,100))
KFDisk = np.zeros((100,100))
RadiceDisk = np.zeros((100,100))


# Foucart_stdev = np.zeros((100,100))
# F_stdev_coarse = np.empty((100,100))


for i in range(100): # iterates through M and Q
    for j in range(100): # iterates through R
        C1 = 1.475*m1[i]/r[j]
        C2 = 1.475*m2[i]/r[j]

        min_c = min(C1,C2)
        max_m = max(m1[i],m2[i])

        M = m1[i]+m2[i]
        
        lam1 = LambdaFromC(C=C1)
        lam2 = LambdaFromC(C=C2)
        lamtilde = Ltilde(lam1,lam2,Q=q[i])
        
        x = NSNS_Mdisk_DCP(q[i],Mtot=M,m=max_m,r=r[j])

       DietrichOrigNoMb(M1=m1[i],M2=m2[i],C1=C1,C2=C2)#+X*NSNS_Mdisk_DCP(Q[i],Mtot=M,m=max_m,r=R[j]) 
        DCPDisk[i,j]=x

        y = NSNS_Mrem_Kruger(min_c) 
        KFDisk[i,j]=y
        diff = abs(x-y)
        Stdev[i,j] = diff
        
        z = NSNS_Mrem_Radice(Ltilde=lamtilde)
        RadiceDisk[i,j]=z


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3,figsize=(25,10))


c1 = ax[0].contourf(R,Q,DCPDisk) #,vmin=0,vmax=0.072,cmap='inferno')
ax[0].set_title('Dietrich Disk')
ax[0].set_xlim(10,13.9)
ax[0].set_xlabel('R (km)')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Q')
ax[0].set_ylim(0.5,0.95)
fig.colorbar(c1,ax=ax[2],cmap='inferno')

c2 = ax[1].contourf(R,Q,KFDisk) #,vmin=0,vmax=0.072,cmap='inferno')
ax[1].set_title('Kruger Disk')
ax[1].set_xlim(10,13.9)
ax[1].set_xlabel('R (km)')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Q')
ax[1].set_ylim(0.5,0.95)
#plt.colorbar()

c3 = ax[2].contourf(R,Q,RadiceDisk)
ax[2].set_title('Radice Disk')
ax[2].set_xlim(10,13.9)
ax[2].set_xlabel('R (km)')
ax[2].set_ylabel('Q')
ax[2].set_ylim(0.5,0.95)


plt.show()
```

This creates the following: [image]

But when I plot them individually, it can be seen that the colormap is different for each figure (as is the case for the above subplots).

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I change the colormapping on the subplots to be common for one colorbar?

Comment: Set the contour levels with the levels keyword argument

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf.html